# Java library for image processing masking task

Tags: java, image-processing, matrix, linear-algebra, masking

Is there any handy library can handle masking operation in Java? Taking care of element by element multiplication, masking boundary elements, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The Java Advanced Imaging API provides a set of object-oriented interfaces that support a simple, high-level programming model which lets you manipulate images easily. :
http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/
Tutorials:
https://jaistuff.dev.java.net/docs/jaitutorial.pdf

2) An API with interesting filters:
http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html